# Generating wide html pages to PDFs

Tags: c#, html, .net, pdf

I'm using C# .Net and want to generate a random size HTML table into PDF. I have tried ExpertPDF and Essential Objects HTMLtoPDF but they seem to mess up on very wide tables.

Any tools or ideas to fix this?

Comment: Is it just simple table or you need some fancy stuff in there as well?/

Comment: Just a simple table with some css. Nothing fancy. They are just so wide sometimes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These tools use html rendering engines like a regular browser. Then they take the rendered content and write it into a pdf. They don't know how to handle wide content (except for scaling it to fit into a pdf page).

You need to change your html (create a printer friendly version of your page that is not that wide) and feed the html to pdf converter something that it can chew.